# Редирект в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect

Суть в том, чтобы все страницы типа
`/katalog/atributika-i-suveniri/kruzhka-bla-bla-bla.html` редиректились на

```
/katalog/atributika-i-suveniri/kruzhki/kruzhka-bla-bla-bla.html
```

Сделал такой редирект:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/kruzhka-(.*)$ $1/kruzhki/kruzhka-$2 [R=301,L]
```

И понятное дело начинается циклическая переадресация из-за второго слова kruzhka и получается что-то типа:

```
/katalog/atributika-i-suveniri/kruzhki/kruzhki/kruzhki/.../kruzhki/kruzhka-bla-bla-bla.html
```

Есть решение?

Answer (score 1):

Чем не вариант?

```
RewriteRule ^/katalog/atributika-i-suveniri/kruzhka-(.*)$ /katalog/atributika-i-suveniri/kruzhki/kruzhka-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Слишком много захватываете регулярками в начале строки, в то время как у вас есть за что уцепиться: "kruzhka" и "kruzhki" делают строку от начала до переменной части url разной.

Comment: Не срабатывает. Куда только не вставлял уже в htaccess. Сайт на Joomla